# Dynamically create HTML table rows with VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am using VBA to create a table in an outlook email. I have figured out how to generate the table, but my problem is that I need to dynamically adjust the number of rows in the table. For some emails, there will be two rows of data, for others there will be three, etc.

In the code below `rowstocontact` is a `Collection`. I know I want to loop through the `Collection` and add a row for each item in the collection, but I can't figure out how to insert a loop within the html code that is creating the table.

Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks.

```
    bodytext = "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse:" & _
    "collapse;}</style></head><body>" & _
    "<table style=""width:60%""><tr>" & _
    "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Reviewee</th>" & _
    "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Manager(s)</th>" & _
    "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Project code</th>" & _
    "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Requested</th>" & _
    "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Type</th>" & _
    "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Due</th></tr><tr>" & _
    "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Range("D" & rowtocontact(1)) & "</td>" & _
    "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Range("L" & rowtocontact(1)) & "</td>" & _
    "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Range("M" & rowtocontact(1)) & "</td>" & _
    "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Range("AJ" & rowtocontact(1)) & "</td>" & _
    "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Range("V" & rowtocontact(1)) & "</td>" & _
    "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Range("AK" & rowtocontact(1)) & "</td>" & _
    "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Range("AK" & rowtocontact(1)) & "</td>" & _
    "</tr></Table></body>"
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to split the HTML into 3 parts and have a string variable for each:

- Everything before the rows
- The rows
- Everything after the rows

In the second section of code you can iterate through the collection (of row references) and dynamically build the table by adding `<tr>...</tr>` blocks for as many items as there are in your `Collection`.

After setting the string for 'everything after the rows' you then concatenate all three parts together to get the final HTML string.

Here is the sample code - note I added a worksheet reference (`ws`) as a best practice and also dropped off the final `<td>` per row as it seemed like a duplicate of the value on column `AK` for which you did not have a header. You can adjust as suits anyway:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateEmailHtml()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim strBeforeRows As String
    Dim strRows As String
    Dim strAfterRows As String
    Dim strAll As String

    ' get a worksheet reference
    Set ws = Sheet1

    ' test collection
    coll.Add 2
    coll.Add 4
    coll.Add 6

    ' HTML before rows
    strBeforeRows = "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse:" & _
        "collapse;}</style></head><body>" & _
        "<table style=""width:60%""><tr>" & _
        "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Reviewee</th>" & _
        "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Manager(s)</th>" & _
        "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Project code</th>" & _
        "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Requested</th>" & _
        "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Type</th>" & _
        "<th bgcolor=""#bdf0ff"">Due</th></tr>"

    ' iterate collection
    strRows = ""
    For lngCounter = 1 To coll.Count
        strRows = strRows & "<tr>"
        strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & ws.Range("D" & coll(lngCounter)).Value & "</td>"
        strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & ws.Range("L" & coll(lngCounter)).Value & "</td>"
        strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & ws.Range("M" & coll(lngCounter)).Value & "</td>"
        strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & ws.Range("AJ" & coll(lngCounter)).Value & "</td>"
        strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & ws.Range("V" & coll(lngCounter)).Value & "</td>"
        strRows = strRows & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & ws.Range("AK" & coll(lngCounter)).Value & "</td>"
        strRows = strRows & "</tr>"
    Next lngCounter

    ' HTML after rows
    strAfterRows = "</table></body>"

    ' final HTML - concatenate the 3 string variables
    strAll = strBeforeRows & strRows & strAfterRows

    Debug.Print strAll

End Sub
```

So, given this sample data:

[image]

You get this HTML as an output - it is formatted nicely through use of the `Tidy` button in the stack snippet editor for readability:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:60%">
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#bdf0ff">Reviewee</th>
      <th bgcolor="#bdf0ff">Manager(s)</th>
      <th bgcolor="#bdf0ff">Project code</th>
      <th bgcolor="#bdf0ff">Requested</th>
      <th bgcolor="#bdf0ff">Type</th>
      <th bgcolor="#bdf0ff">Due</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td "col width=10%">foo2</td>
      <td "col width=10%">bar2</td>
      <td "col width=10%">baz2</td>
      <td "col width=10%">quux2</td>
      <td "col width=10%">qux2</td>
      <td "col width=10%">quuux2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td "col width=10%">foo2</td>
      <td "col width=10%">bar2</td>
      <td "col width=10%">baz2</td>
      <td "col width=10%">quux2</td>
      <td "col width=10%">qux2</td>
      <td "col width=10%">quuux2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td "col width=10%">foo6</td>
      <td "col width=10%">bar6</td>
      <td "col width=10%">baz6</td>
      <td "col width=10%">quux6</td>
      <td "col width=10%">qux6</td>
      <td "col width=10%">quuux6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with a workaround by resizing the range to include 1 cell outside the table, to an unformatted zone:

```
        With Log_03.Range("VBA_rng_email")
            Set RNG = Union(.Resize(iRow), .Offset(.Rows.Count).Resize(1))
        End With
        strbody = strbody & RangetoHTML(RNG) & "<br>"
```

- Where iRow is the number if rows from the table i want to grab